# How to compare vitamin D and glucose levels between patients and controls?

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I want to test the hypothesis of a decreased level of vitamin D in diabetic subjects. For this I have recorded blood glucose and vitamin D levels in 40 cases and 40 controls.

What kind of statistical test can I use to the above hypothesis?

Comment: Are these two matched samples? What is the scale of measurement (e.g., ng/ml for Vitamin D level)?

Answer (score 2):

Generally this sound like a simple [t-test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-test). That is, you have two groups (diabetics and controls) and you measured 1 variable (Vitamin D).

However, some more context/information about your data will lead to a lot better answers. For example, please answer chl's comment.
Second, what is the idea behind measuring the glucose level regarding your hypothesized relation between diabetes and Vitamin D?